# Calling Event 'socket' in http.ClientRequest

Tags: node.js

I am a node newbie and have a question about the socket event in http.ClientRequest. The documentation says

```
Event: 'socket'#
function (socket) { }

Emitted after a socket is assigned to this request.
```

URL: [nodejs documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_socket)

I have the following:

```
var req = http.request(requestOptions, function(res) {
    util.puts('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
    util.puts('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));

    res.setEncoding('utf-8');
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        util.puts('BODY: ' + chunk);
    });
});

req.on('socket', function(sock) {
    util.puts('req.on socket event called');
    util.puts(sock.address());
    util.puts('Remote address: ' + sock.remoteAddress + ':' + sock.remotePort);

});
```

I'm trying to figure out the function(socket){ }. The above socket event has the following output for 
`'util.puts(sock.address());'` and `'util.puts('Remote address: ' + sock.remoteAddress + ':' + sock.remotePort);'`

```
> null
> Remote address: undefined:undefined
```

How can i read the remote address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time the socket is assigned the address has not been assigned. Try this:

```
req.on('socket', function(sock) {
  sock.on('connect', function(connection) {   
    util.puts('req.on socket event called');
    util.puts(util.inspect(sock.address()));
    util.puts('Remote address: ' + sock.remoteAddress + ':' + sock.remotePort);
  });
});
```

Comment: getting an error on connectedSock.address(). util.puts(util.inspect(connectedSock.address()));
                                       ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'address' of undefined